# See NSUserDefaults file content

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Is there any way I can see the content of NSUserDefaults? I'm able to open the plist file using "pico" from the terminal, but it shows weird characters, I can't actually see the content file content. Is there any way I can open the file in Xcode?

Basically, I want to be able to see and edit the content of NSUserDefaults without the need of doing so programmatically, I'd like to do so from the Terminal or from Xcode.
Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm able to open the file using "pico" but it shows weird characters.

Because as an optimization (storage space and read/write speed) iOS stores property list files in the binary format. You need to convert it to XML format using

```
plutil -convert xml1 com.yourapp.bundleid.plist
```

After this, you'll be able to see a meaningful result when opened in a text editor (such as Pico).

Comment: I see, I can see the content and edit it now, will this conversion affect the app? Thanks!

Comment: @user1679865 it won't affect its functionality.

Comment: Thanks, so will xcode still be writing binary data into it? I'm curious to know how does it work under the hood

Comment: @user1679865 when it's overwritten, it will most likely be reverted to binary format (although this is an implementation detail which you should not rely upon and it is not entirely clear how exactly it works.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the defaults command-line tool to easy access the UserDefaults.

```
defaults read <domain> <key>
defaults write <domain> <key> <value>
```

You can also delete keys or the whole domain (bundle id) if you need it.

Comment: @user1679865 it's the defaults domain, in case of a Cocoa application, it's the bundle identifier.

Comment: When I try this I get: The domain/default pair of (my bundle identifier, my key) does not exist, Could that be because of the xml conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You can also open the file in Xcode. Simply double-clicking on it should open it in Xcode.

Comment: I can't navigate to the file from the file browser, when I open "Application Support" there is no "iPhone Simulator" folder, but this folder does show when using the Terminal

Answer (score 0):

As of Mac OS X 10.8, directly editing the contents of user defaults files is very likely to fail randomly. You must use either the defaults command, the NSUserDefaults API, or the CFPreferences API.